# Mission impossible: jQuery attribute selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm getting mad with jQuery selectors.

I'm using the ready-made script that you can find here (live-edit on jQuery, CSS and HTML is available so it's great):

http://codepen.io/robooneus/pen/ivdFH

It filters **li** elements while typing in an input text. So for example when i type "Ap" it hides all **li** elements not containing "Ap". For example below the **li** with "Apple pie" stays visibile meanwhile "Pumpkin pie" doesn't.

```
<ul id="list">
  <li class="in">Apple pie</li>
  <li class="in">Pumpkin pie</li>
<ul>
```

It works but the problem is that inside li I need to put a lot of other stuff like you can see in this example:

```
<ul id="list">
  <li class="in">Apple pie <strong>abc</srong> Hello</li>
  <li class="in">Pumpkin pie <strong>123</srong> Bye</li>
<ul>
```

I don't want the script to search also for "abc", "123", "Hello" and "Bye" so I thought to use an attribute as a sort of index:

```
<ul id="list">
  <li class="in" for="Appe pie">Apple pie <strong>abc</srong> Hello</li>
  <li class="in" for="Pumpkin pie">Pumpkin pie <strong>123</srong> Bye</li>
<ul>
```

In the [for] attribute I put only the words on which I want to perform the live search while I'm typing but I'm unable to edit the script. This is the original code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

  var jobCount = $('#list .in').length;
  $('.list-count').text(jobCount + ' items');


  $("#search-text").keyup(function () {
     //$(this).addClass('hidden');

    var searchTerm = $("#search-text").val();
    var listItem = $('#list').children('li');
    var searchSplit = searchTerm.replace(/ /g, "'):containsi('")

      $.extend($.expr[':'], {
      'containsi': function(elem, i, match, array)
      {
        return (elem.textContent || elem.innerText || '').toLowerCase()
        .indexOf((match[3] || "").toLowerCase()) >= 0;
      }
    });


    $("#list li").not(":containsi('" + searchSplit + "')").each(function(e)   {
      $(this).addClass('hiding out').removeClass('in');
      setTimeout(function() {
          $('.out').addClass('hidden');
        }, 300);
    });

    $("#list li:containsi('" + searchSplit + "')").each(function(e) {
      $(this).removeClass('hidden out').addClass('in');
      setTimeout(function() {
          $('.in').removeClass('hiding');
        }, 1);
    });


      var jobCount = $('#list .in').length;
    $('.list-count').text(jobCount + ' items');

    //shows empty state text when no jobs found
    if(jobCount == '0') {
      $('#list').addClass('empty');
    }
    else {
      $('#list').removeClass('empty');
    }

      });

    });
```

I tryed with every possible combination of the following syntax with no success:

```
li[for]
$("#list li").attr("for")
$("#list li[for]")
```

Belive me, I spent 4 hours on this. At some point I managed to "point" the script in the [for] attribute but in an unwanted and buggy way:

```
$("#list li[for^="'+searchTerm+'"]")
```

I also tryed to debug the code with Firebug Console still with no success.

Comment: Instead of trying to invent a new attribute, try using the `data-` attribute, which already has [built-in support in jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.data/).

Comment: You seriously wrote all this code to achieve something a single method would do?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/

Comment: There you go: http://jsfiddle.net/MelanciaUK/1fxdqzv2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other comments are correct - it's better if you fixed the code to read from an attr like data.

However, instead of embedding the search term in an attribute, another alternative would be to wrap span tags around what is searchable, and adjust the selectors like so:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/cJGfd

HTML:

```
<li class="in"><span>Apple pie</span> Pumpkin</li>
<li class="in"><span>Pumpkin pie</span></li>
<li class="in"><span>Banana-creme pie</span></li>
```

JS:

```
$("#list li span").not(":containsi('" + searchSplit + "')").each(function(e)   {
  $(this).closest('li').addClass('hiding out').removeClass('in');
  setTimeout(function() {
      $('.out').addClass('hidden');
    }, 300);
});

$("#list li span:containsi('" + searchSplit + "')").each(function(e) {
  $(this).closest('li').removeClass('hidden out').addClass('in');
  setTimeout(function() {
      $('.in').removeClass('hiding');
    }, 1);
});
```

Comment: I wasted 4 hours trying to use a tricky approach. Belive me, this was the first thing I thought but for an unknown reason I started to play with attributes. It seems that I'm an XML-feticist. Thank you Will.

Comment: No problem.  Depending on how this needs to scale, you might be better off going the attribute way, but sometimes it's refreshing to try another approach :)